# Ajax tocar audio após execução com sucesso

Tags: javascript, ajax, html5-audio

Preciso tocar um áudio na execução do trecho abaixo, onde exibe os dados encontrados em uma consulta:

```
// Verifica se o Ajax realizou todas as operações corretamente
if(req.readyState == 4) {
    if (req.status == 200) {
        // Resposta retornada pelo PesquisaRomaneio.php
        var resposta = req.responseText;

        // Abaixo colocamos a(s) resposta(s) na div resultado
        document.getElementById('resultado').innerHTML = resposta;
        // Toca audio se encontrou
        var snd = new Audio("../images/alert.mp3"); 
        snd.play();
    } else {
        document.getElementById('resultado').innerHTML = "Erro: " + req.status;
    }

    setTimeout(buscarRomaneio, segundos * 1000);
}
```

Tentei usar o código abaixo, mas não executou. Como posso corrigir isso?

```
 var snd = new Audio("../images/alert.mp3"); 
 snd.play();
```

Comment: Qual é o seu navegador? Testou em outros navegadores?

Comment: Tem certeza que o audio está na pasta `images`?

Comment: Testei no FF, Chrome, Opera e IE. Em nenhum deu certo. O audio está sim na pasta images, para testes... Tentei largando ele na raiz, também não deu certo.

Comment: Funciona se você colocar em alguma pasta que não comece com `..`?

Comment: não, coloquei na pasta que está o js: var snd = new Audio("alert.mp3"); e ainda assim nao tocou...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolvido da seguinte forma (FF, Chrome, Opera):

```
// Verifica se o Ajax realizou todas as operações corretamente
if(req.readyState == 4) {
    if (req.status == 200) {
        // Resposta retornada pelo PesquisaRomaneio.php
        var resposta = req.responseText;

        // Abaixo colocamos a(s) resposta(s) na div resultado
        document.getElementById('resultado').innerHTML = resposta;
        // Toca audio se encontrou
        var snd = new Audio("sounds/alert.mp3"); 
        snd.load();
        snd.play();
    } else {
        document.getElementById('resultado').innerHTML = "Erro: " + req.status;
    }

    setTimeout(buscarRomaneio, segundos * 1000);
}
```

No IE não funcionou dessa forma (a vá...). Então, no arquivo PHP, coloquei dessa forma:

```
while (OCIFetch($consulta)){
    if (!empty($v_romaneio)) {
        echo "<td><b>" . $v_romaneio . "</b></td><br />";
        echo "<embed src='images/alert.mp3'width='1' height='1'>";
    }
}
```